# Powershell - Compare multiple files against single csv files

Tags: powershell

I am trying to compare multiple files against a single document. I have managed to make that part work however where my issue is, is that i want to be able to check if the files exist before a comparison is run.

i.e. check if file A exists, if so compare against master csv file, if not continue on and check if file b exists, if so compare against master csv and so on.

my script so far goes:

```
$files = get-content -path "H:\Compare\File Location\servername Files.txt"
$prod = "H:\compare\Results\master_SystemInfo.csv"

foreach ($file in $files) {

If((Test-Path -path $file))
{
    Write-Host "File exists, comparing against production"

    $content1 = Get-Content "H:\Compare\Results\$file" 
    $content2 = Get-Content $prod

    $comparedLines = Compare-Object $content1 $content2 -IncludeEqual | 
    Sort-Object { $_.InputObject.ReadCount } 

    $lineNumber = 0 
    $comparedLines | foreach {
        $pattern = ".*"

        if($_.SideIndicator -eq "==" -or $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>") 
        { 
            $lineNumber = $_.InputObject.ReadCount 
        } 

        if($_.InputObject -match $pattern) 
        { 
            if($_.SideIndicator -ne "==") 
            { 
                if($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>") 
                { 
                    $lineOperation = "prod" 
                } 
                elseif($_.SideIndicator -eq "<=") 
                { 
                    $lineOperation = "test" 
                } 

                [PSCustomObject] @{ 
                    Line = $lineNumber 
                    File = $lineOperation 
                    Text = $_.InputObject  
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } | Export-Csv "h:\compare\Comparison Reports\Prod.vs.$file" -  NoTypeInformation

}
Else
{ "File does not exist, aborting" ; return}
}
```

The comparison is working just need to add the check for file before running comparison as it is still spitting out results for files that don't exist.

Thank you very much,

Comment: Looks like you are already checking that the file exists using `Test-Path`. The problem might be that you're passing `$files` to `Test-Path` instead of `$file`.

Comment: Thanks @ama1111 however now the script just stops. I removed the ; return from the "Else" area but no comparisons take place now?

Comment: What is the output? A single "File does not exist, aborting"?

Comment: @ama1111 Sorry that was just left over from a single file check which worked i.e. check if file exist if so compare if not stop. I'd just like this to work in a loop now. The "servername files.txt" holds a list of 10 servernames files to check. So the objective is to check the list and of those 10 that have a corresponding file in h:\compare\results then run the comparison against the prod file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer by altering the code, this time im just creating a txt file from the files in the folder first that way i don't need to test-path. This now generates a file list from the folder, then compares each file against the master file and outputs multiple files, one for each comparison saving it as the original filename i.e. "Prod.vs._SystemInfor.csv"

FYI - In the first line the abc123* is a variable i put in to look for specific server names within the folder and generate a file list based on those only. We have a number of servers all with similar naming conventions just the last 4 digits are different depending on where they are located.

Thanks

Working Powershell script:

```
Get-ChildItem -file abc123* H:\Compare\Results -Name | Out-File "H:\Compare\Results\Office Files.txt"
$officefiles = get-content -path "H:\Compare\results\Office Files.txt"

$officeprod = "H:\compare\Results\master_SystemInfo.csv"


foreach ($officefile in $officefiles) {

$content1 = Get-Content "H:\Compare\Results\$officefile" 
$content2 = Get-Content $officeprod

$comparedLines = Compare-Object $content1 $content2 -IncludeEqual | 
Sort-Object { $_.InputObject.ReadCount } 

$lineNumber = 0 
$comparedLines | foreach {
$pattern = ".*"

  if($_.SideIndicator -eq "==" -or $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>") 
{ 
    $lineNumber = $_.InputObject.ReadCount 
} 

if($_.InputObject -match $pattern) 
{ 
    if($_.SideIndicator -ne "==") 
    { 
        if($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>") 
        { 
            $lineOperation = "prod" 
        } 
        elseif($_.SideIndicator -eq "<=") 
        { 
            $lineOperation = "test" 
        } 

        [PSCustomObject] @{ 
            Line = $lineNumber 
            File = $lineOperation 
            Text = $_.InputObject  
        } 
    } 
} 
} | Export-Csv "h:\compare\Comparison Reports\Prod.vs.$officefile" -NoTypeInformation


}
```